# Problem with wireless mouse and internet(crashes) Internet stops working with usb plugged. some times

Tags: networking, mouse, crash, connection

I'm using budgie, ubuntu 20.04.

The mouse works perfectly in a few days.

On other days, it is constantly causing problems.

The internet crashes, I can't access any pages.

When I remove the usb plug the internet comes back instantly.

I plug in the mouse and it works fine for a while, until it crashes again.

Someone experienced, can help me find a solution.

I will definitely not switch systems, ubuntu has been fantastic

It's a laptop. The problem happens, plugged in and unplugged from power.

The log:

(Unplugged energ)

(File1 _ connected usb mouse wifi) internet working

(File2 _ connected usb mouse wifi) error internet

Diff result:>

**MY LOG:**

**dmesg:**

```
+[ 5372.794439] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=138.199.4.67 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=13593 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=35781 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
+[ 5373.358714] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=138.199.4.67 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=13594 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=35781 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
+[ 5374.741360] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=138.199.4.67 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=13595 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=35781 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
+[ 5375.360898] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=138.199.4.67 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=13596 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=35781 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
+[ 5375.617399] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=138.199.4.67 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54 ID=13597 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=35781 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
+[ 5376.216289] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=8.8.4.4 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=103 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=49340 PROTO=UDP SPT=53 DPT=36283 LEN=83 
+[ 5376.631549] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=142.251.129.206 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=15437 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=56814 WINDOW=261 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
+[ 5377.994290] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=104.21.192.174 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52726 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
+[ 5379.787104] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=142.251.129.206 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=56814 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
+[ 5382.031661] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
+[ 5384.178214] wlp1s0: authenticate with c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e
+[ 5384.218409] wlp1s0: send auth to c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e (try 1/3)
+[ 5384.392581] wlp1s0: send auth to c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e (try 2/3)
+[ 5384.597314] wlp1s0: send auth to c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e (try 3/3)
+[ 5384.626316] wlp1s0: authenticated
+[ 5384.629316] wlp1s0: associate with c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e (try 1/3)
+[ 5384.650084] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
+[ 5384.650238] wlp1s0: associated
+[ 5384.935598] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
+[ 5388.180017] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 5
+[ 5498.436011] perf: interrupt took too long (4940 > 4937), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40250
+[ 5664.837759] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x0002a800
+[ 5665.902935] wlp1s0: authenticate with c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e
+[ 5665.925942] wlp1s0: send auth to c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e (try 1/3)
+[ 5665.931894] wlp1s0: authenticated
+[ 5665.933475] wlp1s0: associate with c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e (try 1/3)
+[ 5665.952059] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
+[ 5665.952210] wlp1s0: associated
+[ 5849.542603] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 5974.574016] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 6099.504452] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 6224.970173] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 6350.079477] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 6475.008852] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 6600.040879] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 6724.970029] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 6850.001815] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 6975.033504] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 7099.962962] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 7224.994722] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 7350.026428] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 7474.955831] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 7599.987581] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
+[ 7724.917084] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2   [
7849.948781] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2   [
7974.980505] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2   [
8099.909924] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2  @@
-1666,30 +1710,3 @@  [159688.275712] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=600  [159726.485801] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2   [159851.314145] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
-[159976.345387] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
-[160101.274908] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
-[160242.037108] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48405 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160242.037543] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48406 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160242.049747] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48407 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160242.049777] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48408 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160242.049797] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48409 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160242.049817] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48410 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160242.049836] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48411 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160242.049856] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48412 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160242.049874] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48413 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160242.049894] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48414 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160351.337955] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
-[160489.576006] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=142.250.218.238 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=264 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=43540 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50318 WINDOW=261 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-[160489.576205] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=142.250.218.238 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=264 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=43835 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50318 WINDOW=261 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-[160490.907818] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=142.250.218.238 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=264 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=44096 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50318 WINDOW=261 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-[160531.812635] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29271 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-[160542.181342] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29311 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160542.352150] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29307 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160542.366120] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29309 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160542.378735] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29308 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160542.405003] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29312 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160542.419276] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29314 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160542.440437] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29313 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-[160542.482558] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29315 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-[160549.690275] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=157.240.222.14 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=82 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=84 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=443 DPT=52772 LEN=62 
-[160601.401187] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

**journalctl:**

```
--- Logs begin at Thu 2021-11-11 19:23:34 -03, end at Sat 2021-11-13 16:01:12 -03. --
+-- Logs begin at Thu 2021-11-11 19:23:34 -03, end at Sat 2021-11-13 15:48:56 -03. --  laptop kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x21, date = 2019-02-13  laptop kernel: Linux version
5.4.0-90-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-054) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #101-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 15 20:00:55 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-90.101-generic 5.4.148)  laptop kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-90-generic root=UUID=5c15bf74-1853-48ec-96fc-eacc87a884b6 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7 @@ -21561,151 +21561,3 @@  laptop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.  laptop systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.  laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=-95 txrate=43300
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=-95 txrate=28900
-laptop dbus-daemon[4929]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.592' (uid=1000 pid=144305 comm="/snap/sublime-text/110/opt/sublime_text/sublime_te" label="snap.sublime-text.subl (complain)")
-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
-laptop dbus-daemon[4929]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
-laptop systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
-laptop sh[152717]: laptop-mode: Battery polling disabled
-laptop systemd[1]: lmt-poll.service: Succeeded.
-laptop systemd[1]: Finished Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service.
-laptop systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-74 noise=-95 txrate=26000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-56 noise=-95 txrate=26000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-74 noise=-95 txrate=39000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=-95 txrate=1000
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4a00006 specified for 0x4a0007b.
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4a00006 specified for 0x4a0007b.
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4401874 for 0x4401962 window override-redirect is an override-redirect window and this is not correct according to the standard, so we'll fallback to the first non-override-redirect window 0x440000f.
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x4401874 for 0x4401962 window override-redirect is an override-redirect window and this is not correct according to the standard, so we'll fallback to the first non-override-redirect window 0x440000f.
-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
-laptop sh[152794]: laptop-mode: Battery polling disabled
-laptop systemd[1]: lmt-poll.service: Succeeded.
-laptop systemd[1]: Finished Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service.
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-75 noise=-95 txrate=120000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-62 noise=-95 txrate=120000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=-95 txrate=120000
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: qt5ct: D-Bus system tray: yes
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: qt5ct: custom style sheet is disabled
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x540000a specified for 0x5400008.
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::translate: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-94 noise=-95 txrate=150000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=-95 txrate=135000
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48405 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48406 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48407 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48408 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48409 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48410 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48411 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48412 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48413 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=172.217.173.78 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1470 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x80 TTL=61 ID=48414 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=33488 WINDOW=1050 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-54 noise=-95 txrate=150000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=-95 txrate=43300
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=-95 txrate=60000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-74 noise=-95 txrate=54000
-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
-laptop sh[153009]: laptop-mode: Battery polling disabled
-laptop systemd[1]: lmt-poll.service: Succeeded.
-laptop systemd[1]: Finished Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service.
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x540000a specified for 0x540001f.
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::translate: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-66 noise=-95 txrate=135000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=-95 txrate=135000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=-95 txrate=81000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=-95 txrate=43300
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=-95 txrate=81000
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x540000a specified for 0x5400028.
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=-95 txrate=135000
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::translate: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=-95 txrate=135000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-72 noise=-95 txrate=90000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with c0:25:e9:39:e6:7e [GTK=CCMP]
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x540000a specified for 0x540003d.
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::translate: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=-95 txrate=108000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-73 noise=-95 txrate=108000
-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
-laptop sh[153095]: laptop-mode: Battery polling disabled
-laptop systemd[1]: lmt-poll.service: Succeeded.
-laptop systemd[1]: Finished Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service.
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-63 noise=-95 txrate=121500
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-57 noise=-95 txrate=121500
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-76 noise=-95 txrate=121500
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=-95 txrate=43300
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-75 noise=-95 txrate=121500
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[139523]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=142.250.218.238 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=264 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=43540 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50318 WINDOW=261 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=142.250.218.238 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=264 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=43835 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50318 WINDOW=261 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=142.250.218.238 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=264 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=44096 PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=50318 WINDOW=261 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x540000a specified for 0x540004a.
-laptop budgie-wm.desktop[6440]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x540000a specified for 0x5400053.
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::translate: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop budgie-panel.desktop[152970]: QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29271 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29311 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29307 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29309 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29308 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29312 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29314 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29313 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=200.150.5.82 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=1432 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=88 ID=29315 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=41758 WINDOW=123 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-64 noise=-95 txrate=39000
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=00 SRC=157.240.222.14 DST=192.168.0.102 LEN=82 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=84 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=443 DPT=52772 LEN=62 
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-77 noise=-95 txrate=108000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-66 noise=-95 txrate=39000
-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service...
-laptop sh[153157]: laptop-mode: Battery polling disabled
-laptop systemd[1]: lmt-poll.service: Succeeded.
-laptop systemd[1]: Finished Laptop Mode Tools - Battery Polling Service.
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-78 noise=-95 txrate=43300
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=-95 txrate=1000
-laptop kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC=11 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-74 noise=-95 txrate=60000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=-95 txrate=43300
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-77 noise=-95 txrate=120000
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
-laptop wpa_supplicant[4962]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=-95 txrate=30000
```

Comment: I would be tempted to explore your hardware to ensure it's good I'd use a *live* system, and also likely check your PSU is providing adequate power (*you didn't say if desktop or laptop, but it's somewhat similar*).  As power supplies age, they produce less power, which can make the hardware struggle when more is attached (or after it's been on awhile & the hardware warms, and fans etc. need to turn on thus more power is required..)  If you get the same behavior when a *live* system is utilized; it's likely hardware related (it won't be identical as *live* media will draw different to hdd/ssd)

Comment: how can i check what's going on. Log?? tracking to see where it breaks???

Comment: `dmesg` will show kernel messages; `journalctl` will show systemd log entries... from reading what you gave the question *screamed* check PSU to me.. (*but we tend to focus mostly on issues we see somewhat-regularly so it's just an opinion*)

Comment: Today is working, without problem. waiting the bug start.

Comment: I add log error in question. This problem is very boring, i cant surf online.